# Does synthesis/ PnR tool need create_generated_clock constraint for clock MUX output?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, timing-analysis, sdc

Does Synthesis/PnR tool need a create_generated_clock constraint for clock MUX output ? If yes, why does the tool need such constraint?

My previous understanding is that we only need create_generated_clock for divided clocks from sequential clock dividers.

Comment: This will be in the documentation ... somewhere. You might want to mention which toolchain, so that if anyone feels inclined to answer, they can point to the *right* documentation.

Comment: Does the below response answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

No, generated clock constraint is not needed, because the mux is expected to NOT change the period/phase of the clock, but just feeds forwards one of the input clocks based on the select signal. However, clock gating checks will be done by the tool if the mux select input is dynamically changing.

For such a clock mux, you may need either false path constraint, for eg:

```
set_false_path -from [get_clocks clk_a] -to [get_clocks clk_b]
set_false_path -from [get_clocks clk_b] -to [get_clocks clk_a]
```

OR exclusive clock constraint, for eg:

```
set_clock_groups -logically_exclusive -group clk_a -group clk_b
```

Because these clocks cannot exist together in the design and hence you have to convey to the tool that inter-clock timing need not be analyzed.